# Preserve map scaling in R?

Tags: r

I have some spatial data I am mapping in R using the maps library. Specifically, I am mapping circles on a US map. I have lat/long center coordinates and a radius for each circle, and am mapping them like so:

```
library(maps)
library(plotrix)
map('state')
draw.circle(x=-73.76275, y=41.04181, radius=2)
```

This particular circle needs a radius of 205 km. I have been able to match this up and plot accurately in the graphics window, but zooming or exporting to png changes the circle size in relation to the map.

Is there any way to a) automate the circle size, and b) preserve that scaling when exporting?

Comment: Mapping ranges of latitude to km is pretty easy, about 111 to the degree, but the radius in the longitude directions will not be so easy. You need to figure out ranges first, convert your latitude in degrees to radians and 205/cos(lat)*111 will be the radius in the "x" direction. How you want to handle that will be yur call since my guess is that you will end up taking an average rather than being totally accurate about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
map('state')
x <- -73.76275
y <- 41.04181
radius <- 205 # in kilometers
s <- seq(0,2*pi,length=1000)
yradius <- optimize(interval=c(0,3),f=function(z){
  abs(pointDistance(c(x,y),c(x,y+z),longlat=T) - radius*1000)})$par
xradius <- optimize(interval=c(0,3),f=function(z){
  abs(pointDistance(c(x,y),c(x+z,y),longlat=T) - radius*1000)})$par
lines(cos(s)*xradius+x,sin(s)*yradius+y)
```

This gives you a circle where the northern most point is 205km north of the center and the eastern most point is 205km east of the center.

Comment: For quick and dirty this may be okay.  But consider that larger radius "circles" should not be circular.  An alternative approach may be to produce a circle in the coordinates of an appropriate projection and then use `spTransform()` in the `rgdal` package to get it back to longlat.